# Android: is it possible to configure ListView of ListActivity via xml

Tags: android, listview

Actualy the question in subject... How to configure ListView of ListActivity via xml, for example padding, dividerHeight etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found approprieate solution for me, the only one thing what I need is to declare ListView component with id="@android:id:list" in the root layout for the ListActivity. After that I am uble to customize ListView component which is used for the ListActivity in a normal way via xml.

Comment: the xml attribute to use is `android:id="@id/android:list"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is You can do it via a separate Style xml sheet or you can set it as properties in much the same way as you set the name.

I suggest looking here for more info: [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)